# How to reference client-side input from a cloud page in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I have two microsite cloud pages: (1) to ask a user for the information, and (2) one that takes the information and uses it in a SSJS WSProxy call

The first page captures information like:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <input type="text" name="deCustKey"/>Data Extension External Key<br />
    <input type="text" name="retrieveMid"/>Retrieve MID<br />
    <input type="text" name="createMid"/>Create MID<br />
    <input type="text" name="folderID"/>Target Folder<br />
    <input type="text" name="name"/>Name of New DE<br />
    <input type="text" name="description"/>Description of New DE<br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is that the second microsite page (referenced by the xxxxx above) does not seem to be capturing the variables from this first page.

I have tried using the following in the body tag (which is before my SSJS) and then

```
/* before SSJS */
<input id="deCustKey" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@deCustKey)=%%">
<input id="retrieveMid" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@retrieveMid)=%%">
<input id="createMid" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@createMid)=%%">
<input id="folderID" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@folderID)=%%">
<input id="name" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@name)=%%">
<input id="description" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@description)=%%">

/* within SSJS */
var deCustKey = Variable.GetValue('@deCustKey');
var retrieveMid = Variable.GetValue('@retrieveMid');
var createMid = Variable.GetValue('@createMid');
var folderID = Variable.GetValue('@folderID');
var name = Variable.GetValue('@name');
var description = Variable.GetValue('@description');
```

I have tried a couple others as well, but I am having difficulty passing these variables from client-side input on the first page into variable that I can access within my SSJS.

Thanks!

---

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head> 
<body>

<script runat="server">

Platform.Load('Core', '1');

var deCustKey = Request.GetFormField('deCustKey');
var retrieveMid = Request.GetFormField('retrieveMid');
var createMid = Request.GetFormField('createMid');
var folderID = Request.GetFormField('folderID');
var name = Request.GetFormField('name');
var description = Request.GetFormField('description');

</script>

deCustKey is: <ctrl:var name=deCustKey/><br>
retrieveMid is: <ctrl:var name=retrieveMid />
createMid is: <ctrl:var name=createMid/><br>
folderID is: <ctrl:var name=folderID />
name is: <ctrl:var name=name/><br>
description is: <ctrl:var name=description />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second/processing page, you can use the [GetFormField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesGetFormField.htm) method to capture the form values submitted from the first page:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load('Core', '1');

var deCustKey = Request.GetFormField('deCustKey');
var retrieveMid = Request.GetFormField('retrieveMid');
// etc...
</script>
```

And if you ever need to output these values elsewhere on the second page (e.g., body or within client-side JS):

```
<body>
deCustKey is: <ctrl:var name=deCustKey /><br>
retrieveMid is: <ctrl:var name=retrieveMid />
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips - I tried simplifying both pages to test it and display the values being passed, but it still does not appear to be pulling the variables from the first page. After submitting the data on the first page, it does not redirect as it normally does. It just clears the values from the page.

I will update the above question to show the first and second page.

Comment: The above question was updated to contain your recommendations. Have you encountered this issue before where the values clear and you do not get directed to the second page?

Comment: @Lyle are you using any client-side JS that interacts with the form inputs on the first page?

Comment: I am not using any client side JS at this time. After filling out the first form, I am trying to pass those variables into the server side JS that I have recently added above. Is that not possible? I need those variables because my end goal is taking the inputs (which are details of a target DE) and then user a SSJS that retrieves the structural details of the DE and then creates a copy of it in  the target business unit.

Comment: @Lyle that is definitely possible (I copied and pasted your updated code and it works fine on my end). Have both of the pages been republished? Have you tried loading each of the two pages individually in separate browser tabs to see if any errors are encountered? Have you double-checked that the URL in the `action` parameter is correct?

Comment: @Lyle please edit your question to include the updated code from the first page, if possible (I only see the updated code for the second page)

Comment: @Lyle I was able to reproduce your issue and what you described will happen if the `action` attribute on the first page incorrectly points to itself—make sure the `action` attribute on page one points to page **two**.

Comment: Hi @Mark - I went through the code and refreshed everything, but was still having the same issues. I created the microsites from scratch and now everything is passing the variables perfectly. I also swapped in my code to use the details for retrieving/creating the new data extension and it works as well. Thank you again for the insight! I do have one final question - is microsites the best route for this or would you recommend normal landing pages?

Comment: Hi @mark - I see that as well now. That must have somehow gotten updated. It ended up resolving itself when i recreated them because the proper links were selected. Thank you for validating the error!